# swift + OS X sandboxing: treat 'NSVBOpenPanel' as a 'NSOpenPanel' :: because I need to get the sender in the delegate method

Tags: swift, macos, appstore-sandbox

Im using swift and I show a NSOpenPanel. In the delegate I need to look at the sender's prompt to distinguish which action to take:

e.g.

```
func show() {
    ... 
    panel.delegate = self
    panel.prompt = "xy"

    panel.run ....
}

func show2() {
    ... 
    panel.delegate = self
    panel.prompt = "abc"

    panel.run ....
}

//delegate
func panel(sender: AnyObject, shouldEnableURL url: NSURL) -> Bool {
    let panelPrompt = (sender as! NSOpenPanel).prompt       ... 
}
```

- without sandbox = WORKS fine

  - the sender of the delegate is a NSOpenPanel indeed
- with sandbox = Cast fails, crash

  - the sender of the delegate is NOT a NSOpenPanel but a NSVBOpenPanel. Apple's private class that remotely speaks to the outside world and allows the user to choose files NORMALLY not in your sandbox. (for details I refer to apple's sandboxing guide)

---

So the question is how do I do use this in swift without crashing?
Is there a nice way or is it just a bug/ugly idk behavior
Do I have to revert to use performSelector?

===

Addition: extensions to NSOpenPanel don't work either!

Comment: What is NSVBOpenPanel? It is mentioned in the title, but occurs nowhere in the question or answer.

Comment: sorry. youre right.. NSVVB stuff is apple's private sandbox open panel variant which should behave different at all AFAICS. Ill edit the question right away

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of casting the sender to `NSOpenPanel` (which fails because the
sender is an instance of the private `NSVBOpenPanel` class),
or some `performSelector` magic, you can use the fact that
arbitrary methods and properties can be accessed on `AnyObject`
*without casting*, and the call behaves like an implicitly 
unwrapped optional:

```
func panel(sender: AnyObject, shouldEnableURL url: NSURL) -> Bool {
    let panelPrompt = sender.prompt ?? ""
    // ...
    return true
}
```

This gives the prompt for *any* `sender` object which has a `prompt`
property, and the empty string as a fallback. In my test it worked well
in a sandboxed environment.

See [The strange behaviour of Swift's AnyObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33388830/the-strange-behaviour-of-swifts-anyobject) for more details, examples, and references to the
documentation.

Comment: Strange, but this does work with `AnyObject`. The `sender` seems to be immutable, however. How do you mutate it? Say needing to call `sender.directoryURL = newURL`

Comment: bug when setting `AnyObject` parameters: https://forums.swift.org/t/anyobject-parameter-cannot-assign-to-immutable-expression/16642

Comment: @pkamb have you found out how to change the directory of `NSVBOpenPanel`? I'm looking for a Swift version of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682666/restrict-access-to-certain-folders-using-nsopenpanel

Answer (score 0):

This is how it would work with performSelector. It is quite ugly though:

```
let panelPromptUnmanaged = (sender as! NSObject).performSelector(NSSelectorFromString("prompt"))
let panelPrompt = panelPromptUnmanaged != nil ? panelPromptUnmanaged.takeRetainedValue() as! String : ""
```